# Securing mobile REST Api with spring Security enough?

Tags: api, security, rest, spring-security

I'm planing to make a little mobile app that will rely on a java (spring-spring mvc) rest API. 
The API will have paths that look like this for example:

/rest/account  POST (will create a new account (account is composed of a username+pass+email)

/rest/photo/like for example that modify behaviour and add things to the DB...

I'm also planing to use Spring Security to handle the authentication/authorisation. 
So the mobile app before to make any authorise call (for example to /rest/photo/like) it will have to login (so the basically to /security_check?j_username=username&password

And from now on every request will have to include the JSESSIONID in the cookie.

My question is, is this secure enough? Do I have to use OAUTH2? Or is it overkill?

Bonus question: As you don't need to be authenticated to make the /rest/account call to create an account, what is the best way to avoid that a user create 1000000 accounts ??
Apache/ip-filter? Or should I handle this in some interceptor in spring-mvc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Yes, from your requirements description I will say Spring Security will do fine. (REST services are usually stateless instead of using sessions, but Spring Security can handle both.)

**2)** You don't need to use OAuth2 unless you want to pull information from user's Google or Facebook account or something like that.

**3)** The bonus question is not trivial. A common way is to use a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA). You could use OAuth to for example limit the user to one account for every Google/Facebook/X account they have.